# how to add dynamically product to bundle product based on product category

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, category-products

I have code for bundle product.But i need to add product dynamically based on category 'product_id' => '551' here i need to add product dynamically.
please some one help me

```
$bundleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$bundleProduct
->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID) //you can set data in store scope
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
    ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
    ->setTypeId('bundle') //product type
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
//     ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
    ->setSkuType(0) //SKU type (0 - dynamic, 1 - fixed)
    ->setSku('bundlexx1') //SKU
    ->setName('test bundle product96') //product name
    ->setWeightType(0) //weight type (0 - dynamic, 1 - fixed)
//        ->setWeight(4.0000)
    ->setShipmentType(0) //shipment type (0 - together, 1 - separately)
    ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
    ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
    ->setColor(24)
    ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
    ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
    ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
    ->setPriceType(0) //price type (0 - dynamic, 1 - fixed)
    ->setPriceView(0) //price view (0 - price range, 1 - as low as)
    ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
    /*only available if price type is 'fixed'*/
//        ->setPrice(11.22) //price, works only if price type is fixed
 //        ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
//        ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
 //        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
//        ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
//        ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    /*only available if price type is 'fixed'*/
    ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
    ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
    ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
    ->setDescription('This is a long description')
    ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
    ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
    ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        )
    )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(4, 10)); //assign product to categories

$bundleOptions = array();
$bundleOptions = array(
    '0' => array( //option id (0, 1, 2, etc)
        'title' => 'item01', //option title
        'option_id' => '',
        'delete' => '',
        'type' => 'select', //option type
        'required' => '1', //is option required
        'position' => '1' //option position
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'title' => 'item02',
        'option_id' => '',
        'delete' => '',
        'type' => 'multi',
        'required' => '1',
        'position' => '1'
    )
);

$bundleSelections = array();
$bundleSelections = array(
    '0' => array( //option ID
        '0' => array( //selection ID of the option (first product under this option (option ID) would have ID of 0, second an ID of 1, etc)
            'product_id' => '554', //if of a product in selection
            'delete' => '',
            'selection_price_value' => '10',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1
        ),

        '1' => array(
            'product_id' => '553',
            'delete' => '',
            'selection_price_value' => '10',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1
        )
    ),
    '1' => array( //option ID
        '0' => array(
            'product_id' => '552',
            'delete' => '',
            'selection_price_value' => '10',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1
        ),

        '1' => array(
            'product_id' => '551',
            'delete' => '',
            'selection_price_value' => '10',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1
        )
    )
);
//flags for saving custom options/selections
$bundleProduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$bundleProduct->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$bundleProduct->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

//registering a product because of Mage_Bundle_Model_Selection::_beforeSave
Mage::register('product', $bundleProduct);

//setting the bundle options and selection data
$bundleProduct->setBundleOptionsData($bundleOptions);
$bundleProduct->setBundleSelectionsData($bundleSelections);

$bundleProduct->save();
echo 'success';
} catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::log($e->getMessage());
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```